# Formatting Matrix with Labels

Tags: java, matrix, formatting

Ok so this is probably a very basic question but I for the life of me cannot figure out Java output formatting, I just haven't had any practice with it. I am constructing a Term Document Matrix that counts the occurrences of certain words within a series of sentences. The matrix comes out fine with the following code

```
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<columns; j++){
                System.out.print(String.format("%3s", matrix[i][j]));
            }
            System.out.println("");
}
```

Outputting this:

```
  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  2  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  2  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  2  0  0
  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  2  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  2  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

However I would like to add row and column identifiers so that it looks more like this (The column Headers come from a string Array and there would be 20 sentences):

```
             applianc, around, autonom, averag, bath, bedroom, car, charg, drive, eat, home, hour, hous, includ, kilomet, kitchen, lap, larg, live, mile, over, per, pet, road, room, second, sedan, size, test, up, updat, veri, water
Sentence 1:

Sentence 2:

Sentence 3:
.
.
.
```

With the rows and columns lining up so that they are easily identifiable, perhaps with grid or something as seperators. I am clueless as to how to make this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following your example, something like this should work

```
String[] columns = {"applianc", " around", " autonom", " averag", " bath", " bedroom", " car", " charg", " drive", " eat", " home", " hour", " hous", " includ", " kilomet", " kitchen", " lap", " larg", " live", " mile", " over", " per", " pet", " road", " room", " second", " sedan", " size", " test", " up", " updat", " veri", " water"};
int[][] matrix = {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};


System.out.print(String.format("%" + ("sentence ".length() + ("" + matrix.length).length() + 2) + "s"," "));

for(int i=0; i<columns.length; i++){
    System.out.print(columns[i]);
}

System.out.println("");

for(int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("sentence " + String.format("%" + ("" + matrix.length).length() + "S", (i + 1)) + ": ");

    for(int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++){
        System.out.print(String.format("%" + columns[j].length() + "s", matrix[i][j]));
    }

    System.out.println("");
}
```

Output:

```
             applianc around autonom averag bath bedroom car charg drive eat home hour hous includ kilomet kitchen lap larg live mile over per pet road room second sedan size test up updat veri water
sentence  1:        0      0       1      0    0       0   0     0     0   0    0    1    0      0       0       0   0    0    0    1    0   1   0    1    0      0     1    0    0  1     0    0     0
sentence  2:        0      0       0      0    0       0   1     0     0   0    0    2    0      0       1       0   0    0    0    1    0   2   0    0    0      1     0    0    0  0     0    0     0
sentence  3:        0      0       0      0    1       1   0     0     0   1    1    0    0      0       0       1   0    1    0    0    0   0   0    0    3      0     0    1    0  0     0    0     0
sentence  4:        0      1       0      0    0       0   0     1     0   0    0    0    0      0       1       0   0    0    0    1    0   0   0    1    0      0     0    0    1  0     0    0     0
sentence  5:        0      0       0      0    0       1   0     0     0   0    1    0    0      0       0       0   0    1    0    0    0   0   0    0    2      0     0    0    0  0     0    0     0
sentence  6:        0      0       0      0    0       0   1     1     0   0    0    0    0      0       1       0   0    0    0    1    0   1   0    0    0      0     0    0    0  1     0    0     0
sentence  7:        0      1       1      0    0       0   0     0     0   0    0    2    0      0       1       0   1    0    0    1    0   2   0    0    0      0     1    0    0  0     0    0     0
sentence  8:        1      0       0      0    0       0   0     0     0   0    0    0    0      1       0       0   0    0    0    0    0   0   1    0    0      0     0    0    0  0     0    0     1
sentence  9:        0      0       0      0    1       1   0     0     0   0    1    0    1      0       0       0   0    0    0    0    0   0   0    0    1      0     0    0    0  0     0    0     0
sentence 10:        0      0       0      0    0       0   0     0     0   0    0    0    0      0       0       0   0    0    0    0    0   0   1    0    0      0     0    0    0  0     0    0     0
sentence 11:        0      0       1      0    0       0   1     0     1   0    0    0    0      0       1       0   0    0    0    0    0   0   0    1    0      0     0    0    1  0     0    0     0
sentence 12:        0      0       0      0    0       2   0     0     0   0    0    0    0      0       0       0   0    1    0    0    0   0   0    0    2      0     0    3    0  0     0    0     0
sentence 13:        0      0       1      0    0       0   0     0     0   0    0    0    0      0       1       0   0    0    0    1    1   0   0    0    0      0     0    0    0  0     0    0     0
sentence 14:        0      0       0      0    0       0   0     0     0   0    0    0    1      0       0       1   0    0    0    0    0   0   0    0    0      0     0    0    0  2     2    0     0
sentence 15:        0      0       1      0    0       0   1     0     0   0    0    0    0      0       0       0   0    0    0    0    0   0   0    1    0      0     0    0    0  0     0    0     0
sentence 16:        0      0       0      1    0       0   0     0     0   0    0    0    0      0       0       0   0    0    0    2    1   1   0    0    0      0     1    0    0  0     0    0     0
sentence 17:        0      0       0      0    1       1   0     0     0   0    1    0    0      0       0       0   0    0    0    0    0   0   0    0    1      0     0    0    0  0     0    0     0
sentence 18:        1      0       0      0    0       0   0     0     0   1    0    0    1      0       0       2   0    0    0    0    0   0   0    0    0      0     0    0    0  1     1    0     0
sentence 19:        0      1       0      1    0       0   1     0     0   0    0    1    0      0       0       0   1    0    0    2    0   1   0    1    0      1     0    0    0  0     0    0     0
sentence 20:        0      0       0      0    1       1   0     0     0   2    0    0    1      1       0       1   0    0    0    0    0   0   0    0    3      0     0    0    0  0     0    0     1
```

Comment: actually it might even be better to have the same column width, i.e. same character count, so that "applianc" and "up" have the same width